# Xpath always clicks on first child <li> python

Tags: python, html, selenium, onclick, html-lists

I'm trying to press on few links using the code:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@onclick[contains(text(),"+origin_iata_code+")]]").click()
```

The `origing_iata_code` is the object in:

```
['FLL', 'MCO', 'AFL', 'ATM', 'AJU', 'ARU', 'AAX', 'NVT', 'BRA', 'JTC',...]
```

And the code I'm tring to click on had a unique thing for all but it always press just the `FLL` one

```
<li onclick="selecionou('FLL', this,'.txtBusca1', 'true', 'origem', 'Estouem1', 'FLL');">
..
</li>
<li onclick="selecionou('MCO', this,'.txtBusca1', 'true', 'origem', 'Estouem1', 'MCO');">
..
</li>
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you forget to add quotes.

```
("//li[@onclick[contains(text(),'"+origin_iata_code+"')]]")
```

and you have to use `.` instead of `text()`

Go with this

```
  //li[@onclick[contains(.,'FLL')]]
```

or

```
  //li[contains(@onclick,'FLL')]
```

So go with

```
 ("//li[@onclick[contains(.,'"+origin_iata_code+"')]]")
```

Comment: I find that i can prevent this sort of mistake from happening by using string formatting:  find_element_by_xpath("//li[@onclick[contains(.,'%s')]]" % origin_iata_code)   so easy to forget quotes in this case.